# bootgrid checkbox rowSelection is not working

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, jquery-bootgrid

I just want to repost a Question which was asked:

[Bootgrid select row when checkbox is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34329023/bootgrid-select-row-when-checkbox-is-clicked)

I have the same problem now and there was still no answer. Is there anyone who knows how to fix the bug?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself here:

https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-bootgrid/issues/184

It's a bug which can be fixed by adding the code like descri

Answer (score 0):

rowSelect:Enables entire row click selection (sorting must be set to true as well). Default value is false.
So need to set Also **sorting must be set to true**
and bug issue if select multiSelect: true then may be its works.